# I have a question. Why is the particle に instead of は for this sentence? Isnt the one doing supposed to be は not に? Thank you

Tags: grammar, conjugations, japanese-to-english

I have a question. Why is the particle に instead of は for this sentence?
“私に何かできることがあれば”
Isnt the one doing supposed to be は not に? Thank you
[image]